# JavaScript object method return statement

Tags: javascript, oop, return

In JavaScript I created an User class. I wrote a method(function) to this, but i can't give a return statement. Here is my class:

```
function User() {
    var isLogedIn = "FukkaMukka";
    var mail = "";
    var name = "";

    //functions

    this.isLogedInFn = function(callback) {
        $.post("controller.php?module=login&action=test", function(e) {
            this.isLogedIn = false; // Here i can't reach the object variable.. why?
            return e;
        })
    }
    this.logIn = logIn;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable Scope: this.remove is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754273/variable-scope-this-remove-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I am surprised nobody else has said this, but ... **return inside $.post is useless** because it runs "asynchronously". Also, `isLoggedIn` is the correct spelling ;-)

Comment: Oh, also I am "closing as not a real question" because no details of *what the actual problem* is were given, and no *specific question* about this issue was asked. If they were, it could be identified as one of the million duplicates :(

Answer (score 1):

The callback is not executed in the [context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of your object. Several ways to work around:

- call [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with the `context` parameter
- [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) your function to your object
- store a reference to your object in a variable use that (like Sarfraz suggested)

Answer (score 0):

```
function User() {
    var isLogedIn = "FukkaMukka";
    var mail = "";
    var name = "";
    var self = this;
    //functions

    this.isLogedInFn = function(callback) {
        $.post("controller.php?module=login&action=test", function(e) {
            // `this` is no longer in the scope of the function as you would think it would be. in this case `this` iirc will reference the window object.
            self.isLogedIn = false; 
            return e;
        })
    }
    this.logIn = logIn;

}
```

see comments in code.

Comment: I changed the "this" to "self" but not working ...

Comment: you also need to define `self`... see the declaration above `//functions`